# Implementing vector for arbitrary dimensions with UOM

Tags: rust, rust-uom

I am trying to make a simple type that will be backed by an array in the default units of a given dimension in [`uom`](https://docs.rs/uom/latest/uom/). The idea is pretty simple: I provide a constructor that converts quantities to base units and getters that convert them back to desired units for some given dimension:

```
use anyhow::Result;
use core::marker::PhantomData;
use uom::si::{
    Dimension, Quantity, SI, Unit,
    length::{Dimension as Length, meter}
};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Coordinate<D: Dimension + ?Sized> {
    buf: [f64; 2],
    dim: PhantomData<D>,
}

impl<D: Dimension + ?Sized> Coordinate<D>
{
    pub fn new<U: Unit>(x: f64, y: f64) -> Self {
        Self {
            buf: [
                Quantity::<D, SI<f64>, f64>::new::<U>(x).value,
                Quantity::<D, SI<f64>, f64>::new::<U>(y).value,
            ],
            dim: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    pub fn x(&self) -> Quantity<D, SI<f64>, f64> {
        Quantity::<D, SI<f64>, f64> { dimension: PhantomData, units: PhantomData, value: self.buf[0], }
    }

    pub fn y(&self) -> Quantity<D, SI<f64>, f64> {
        Quantity::<D, SI<f64>, f64> { dimension: PhantomData, units: PhantomData, value: self.buf[1], }
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let n = Coordinate::<Length>::new::<meter>(1.0, 1.0);
    println!("{n:?}");
    Ok(())
}
```

This results in more compiler errors than I expected:

```
   Compiling scratchpad v0.1.0 (/home/joe/scratchpad)
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `new` found for struct `Quantity<D, dyn Units<f64, amount_of_substance = mole, electric_current = ampere, length = meter, luminous_intensity = candela, mass = kilogram, thermodynamic_temperature = kelvin, time = second>, f64>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:19:46
   |
19 |                 Quantity::<D, SI<f64>, f64>::new::<U>(x).value,
   |                                              ^^^ function or associated item not found in `Quantity<D, dyn Units<f64, amount_of_substance = mole, electric_current = ampere, length = meter, luminous_intensity = candela, mass = kilogram, thermodynamic_temperature = kelvin, time = second>, f64>`
   |
   = note: the full type name has been written to '/home/madphysicist/scratchpad/target/debug/deps/scratchpad-dd83b867192bd049.long-type-10545255888401044867.txt'
   = note: the function or associated item was found for
           - `Quantity<(dyn Dimension<I = Z0, J = Z0, Kind = (dyn Kind + 'static), L = PInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>>, M = Z0, N = Z0, T = PInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>>, Th = Z0> + 'static), U, V>`
           - `Quantity<(dyn Dimension<I = Z0, J = Z0, Kind = (dyn Kind + 'static), L = PInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>>, M = Z0, N = Z0, T = NInt<UInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>, B0>>, Th = Z0> + 'static), U, V>`
           - `Quantity<(dyn Dimension<I = Z0, J = Z0, Kind = (dyn Kind + 'static), L = PInt<UInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>, B0>>, M = PInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>>, N = Z0, T = NInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>>, Th = Z0> + 'static), U, V>`
           - `Quantity<(dyn Dimension<I = Z0, J = Z0, Kind = (dyn Kind + 'static), L = Z0, M = Z0, N = PInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>>, T = Z0, Th = Z0> + 'static), U, V>`
           and 106 more types

error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `new` found for struct `Quantity<D, dyn Units<f64, amount_of_substance = mole, electric_current = ampere, length = meter, luminous_intensity = candela, mass = kilogram, thermodynamic_temperature = kelvin, time = second>, f64>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:20:46
   |
20 |                 Quantity::<D, SI<f64>, f64>::new::<U>(y).value,
   |                                              ^^^ function or associated item not found in `Quantity<D, dyn Units<f64, amount_of_substance = mole, electric_current = ampere, length = meter, luminous_intensity = candela, mass = kilogram, thermodynamic_temperature = kelvin, time = second>, f64>`
   |
   = note: the full type name has been written to '/home/madphysicist/scratchpad/target/debug/deps/scratchpad-dd83b867192bd049.long-type-10545255888401044867.txt'
   = note: the function or associated item was found for
           - `Quantity<(dyn Dimension<I = Z0, J = Z0, Kind = (dyn Kind + 'static), L = PInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>>, M = Z0, N = Z0, T = PInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>>, Th = Z0> + 'static), U, V>`
           - `Quantity<(dyn Dimension<I = Z0, J = Z0, Kind = (dyn Kind + 'static), L = PInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>>, M = Z0, N = Z0, T = NInt<UInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>, B0>>, Th = Z0> + 'static), U, V>`
           - `Quantity<(dyn Dimension<I = Z0, J = Z0, Kind = (dyn Kind + 'static), L = PInt<UInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>, B0>>, M = PInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>>, N = Z0, T = NInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>>, Th = Z0> + 'static), U, V>`
           - `Quantity<(dyn Dimension<I = Z0, J = Z0, Kind = (dyn Kind + 'static), L = Z0, M = Z0, N = PInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>>, T = Z0, Th = Z0> + 'static), U, V>`
           and 106 more types

error[E0277]: `dyn Dimension<I = Z0, J = Z0, Kind = (dyn Kind + 'static), L = PInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>>, M = Z0, N = Z0, T = Z0, Th = Z0>` doesn't implement `Debug`
  --> src/main.rs:37:15
   |
37 |     println!("{n:?}");
   |               ^^^^^ `dyn Dimension<I = Z0, J = Z0, Kind = (dyn Kind + 'static), L = PInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>>, M = Z0, N = Z0, T = Z0, Th = Z0>` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `Debug`
   |
   = help: the trait `Debug` is not implemented for `dyn Dimension<I = Z0, J = Z0, Kind = (dyn Kind + 'static), L = PInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>>, M = Z0, N = Z0, T = Z0, Th = Z0>`
   = help: the following other types implement trait `Debug`:
             (dyn Any + 'static)
             (dyn Any + Send + 'static)
             (dyn Any + Send + Sync + 'static)
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` which comes from the expansion of the macro `println` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0599.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `scratchpad` (bin "scratchpad") due to 3 previous errors
```

For completeness, here is the contents of `/home/madphysicist/scratchpad/target/debug/deps/scratchpad-dd83b867192bd049.long-type-10545255888401044867.txt`:

```
$ cat /home/madphysicist/scratchpad/target/debug/deps/scratchpad-dd83b867192bd049.long-type-10545255888401044867.txt
Quantity<D, (dyn uom::si::Units<f64, amount_of_substance = uom::si::amount_of_substance::mole, electric_current = uom::si::electric_current::ampere, length = uom::si::length::meter, luminous_intensity = uom::si::luminous_intensity::candela, mass = uom::si::mass::kilogram, thermodynamic_temperature = uom::si::thermodynamic_temperature::kelvin, time = uom::si::time::second> + 'static), f64>
```

I am having hard time correlating the error messages about the missing `new` method and the documentation, which describes it for [`Quantity`](https://docs.rs/uom/latest/uom/si/struct.Quantity.html).

How can I make this code work?

Comment: In `Coordinate::new()`, why are you creating the `Quantity` then only using its `value` field? The struct you created will be dropped; it's the same as doing `buf: [x, y]`. Why wouldn't you just store the `Quantity` directly?

Comment: As for why `Quantity::...::new()` isn't working, I'm not entirely sure. Though, since you already create the `Quantity` struct directly in your `x()` and `y()` methods, why not use the same syntax in `new()`?

Comment: @NicholasCrothers. `Quantity::<D, SI<f64>, f64> { dimension: PhantomData, units: PhantomData, value: self.buf[0], }` creates a new quantity in the default unit for `D, SI<f64>`. That's the unit that `buf` implicitly stores its values in.

Comment: @NicholasCrothers. `Quantity::<D, SI<f64>, f64>::new::<U>(x).value` is creating a new quantity with `x` in units `U`. The `<U>` is very important in this case. When I then extract the value `value`, it's presumably converted to the default units for `D, SI<f64>`. I'm using the constructor to do unit conversion for me.

Comment: @NicholasCrothers. One possible solution might be to replace `Quantity::<D, SI<f64>, f64>::new::<U>(x).value` with an alternative method to convert the value, but I have no idea how to do that in UOM.

Comment: Ah I understand better now. Sorry I haven't used `uom` before, just trying to provide advice based on my Rust knowledge. Based on the [documentation page for `Quantity`](https://docs.rs/uom/latest/uom/si/struct.Quantity.html), `Quantity` is only implemented for a more specialized version of `D`: variations on `dyn Dimension<...>`. I suspect the issue is you need to provide an `impl` that specifies `D` to be a more specific `dyn Dimension` with the associated types defined.

Comment: @NicholasCrothers. That would be bad. I raised an issue on GitHub to ask the maintainer if there's a way to obtain a value converted to its "natural" units